# Analytic solution of the equation $c\int_0^t x^{a-1}e^{-x}dx + (c+e^t)e^{-t}t^{a-1} = 0$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I would like to find the **closed form** solution of the equation in the title for the parameter $t$ when $-1<c<0$ and $0<a<1$.

I tried to use the Laplace transform. The transformation of both sides leads to the following:

$ s^{-a}+c(1+s)^{1-a}s^{-1} = 0$

which can be solved for $s$ :

$s=(1-(-c)^{\frac{1}{1-a}})^{-1}-1$

Is there a way to find the solution of the original equation using this or any other method to solve the problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: concerning the integral: integral of polynomial.exp = another polynomial.exp -> you can get it that way.

Comment: Could you explain this in more details?

Comment: oh, $a$ is not an integer here ! So long for polynomials.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not integer :/

Comment: I don't think it makes sens to solve after transform: what you transform is the function on left part, not the scalar x obeying the equation. Once you have the transform, you might try to transform back into a nicer function than the original if it is possible, then solve.

Comment: I would like something like this:  t = f(c,a)

Comment: NB: the integral is $\Gamma(a+1)-\Gamma(a+1,t)$, but I'm not sure it helps  a lot.

Comment: Yes, it is the lower incomplete gamma.

Comment: But without the "+1" I think: $\Gamma(a)-\Gamma(a,t)$

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

hint: if you derivate the left part, the derivative is alot simpler. Then you can probably reintegrate, and fit the integration constant, thus getting a simpler equivalent equation to solve.

Comment: Thank you! Would you show me this please? :)

Comment: diff = $(ce^{-t}+1)(a-1)t^{a-2}$  ; int(diff) = $-c(a-1)\Gamma(a-1,t)+t^{a-1}+const$ . Fit $const$ using a given value of t (e.g., 0 :-) ), and you get another expression of the initial formula, that you can then solve against 0.

Comment: I think it doesn't help, because in this case we also have the upper incomplete gamma $\Gamma(a-1,t)$ in the equation and the solution of this expression is not easier. Maybe this problem cannot be solved in a closed form, but thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: At least we have  $c(a−1)(Γ(a−1)-Γ(a−1,t))+t^{a−1}$=0 but ok, it's not an explicit $t(c,a)$ .